# How to use compiler included build (Vue, Typescript, Webpack)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I'm getting the error:

```
You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.
```

On my project running with Vue, Typescript & Webpack and I didn't find any solution to fix the problem.
What I tried so far:

- Adding `"vue": { "runtimeCompiler": true }` to `package.json`
- Use `new Vue({render: h => h(MyComponent)}).$mount()` (already using it)

The code (only the important parts):

```js
# webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  target: 'node', // To use Node API trough electron
  entry: 'app/index.ts',
  output: { path: '/dist', filename: 'frontend.js' },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        include: /app/,
        options: { appendTsSuffixTo: ['/\.vue$/'] }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
  }
  externals: [nodeExternals()]
}
```

```js
# app/index.ts

new Vue({render: h => h(AppComponent)}).$mount('#app')
```

```
# app/components/app.component.ts
@Component({ template: require('./app.component.html') }
export default class AppComponent extends Vue {}
```

As you can see, I do not use `.vue` and the error is triggered by using `@Component({ template: require('./app.component.html') }`.

Is there a workaround to split files without using `template` or is it possible to use the compiler included build ?

Answer (score 1):

Setting option `runtimeCompiler` worked for me. But it is not required as package `vue-template-compiler` is included by default. This code snippet may help you as it expands to a `render()` function:

```
import { compileToFunctions } from 'vue-template-compiler'

component: Vue.component("Hola", {
  ...compileToFunctions('<div>Hello user number {{ 1 + 1 }}</div>')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a section in the [vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only). Under "Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only", they describe what to add for the respective build systems.